# Avoiding using the eval function in a loop Python

Tags: python, eval

I have a certain function (Quash) which i want to use to run over a list of variables e.g. a list called 'list'. Is there a way I can run this over the list of numbers without using eval?

NB: I have put the QUash function here only for the sake of simplicity. The really function is more complicated with lots of strings.

Is there an alternative to using the eval function in this loop to have the value extracted?

```
list = [1,2,3,4]

def stringfunction(Var): 
    AnalysisVar = "Quash.(" + str(Var) + ")"
    return AnalysisVar

CompleteNames = [stringfunction(i) for element in list]

for i in CompleteNames:
    eval("%s" %CompleteNames[i])
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `[stringfunction(i) for element in list]` is not going to work.

Comment: Yes@ Klaus D. the thing is I can't put the details of the entire function online. I have just put this in to simplify this as far as possible.

Comment: You have simplified the question to the point of unanswerability.

Comment: You have to add enough code to allow to reproduce the problem directly.

Comment: Ok Will use Map then . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's a bad idea to name your list "list" as that name is already used in Python. Second, just update your list comprehension:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]

CompleteNames = [Quash(str(i)) for i in my_list]
```

Comment: Thank you for that @Aaron Hampton but the function is a bit more complicated than that. I put a simple string over here for the sake of simplicity. Is there another way to do this as well without using the eval function? Really appreciate your help though

Comment: Feedback noted. Also will name my list something better than list.

Comment: You should update your question with a more detailed description of what you want to do then.

Comment: Can you provide a more realistic example? I'm not sure what would make it too complicated for this to work, so there might be better options if I have more info. You could use the built in map function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map

Comment: Yes, what Aaron said.